# Comparing specific columns from embedded data frames within separate lists

Tags: r, list, dataframe, loops, intersection

Suppose I have two lists with the following embedded data frames:

```
# Data frames to intersect
US <- data.frame("Group" = c(1,2,3), "Age" = c(21,20,17), "Name" = c("John","Dora","Helen"))
CA <- data.frame("Group" = c(2,3,4), "Age" = c(21,20,19), "Name" = c("John","Dora","Dan"))
JP <- data.frame("Group" = c(4,5,6), "Age" = c(16,15,14), "Name" = c("Mac","Hector","Jack"))

# Lists to compare----
list1<-list(US,CA,JP)
names(list1)<-c("US","CA","JP")

# List 2 can serve as a "reference list," a duplicate of the first.
list2<-list(US,CA,JP)
names(list2)<-c("US","CA","JP")
```

I have a second list, that serves as a "reference list" to the first. It is copy and is only meant to be used as a reference in some operation, like a for loop. What I want to do is `intersect` the scalars / values from only the first column (e.g. `Group`), and store the intersected output in separate data frames or matrices. I do not want to intersect dataframe groups that have the same names(i.e. List 1 US groups **should not** be intersected with List 2 US groups).

Ideally, a final list of DFs would be created, containing all possible combinations of intersected DF, their names and the results for final output would be something to the effect of:

```
print(comb_list)
$US_CA
  Group
1     2    
2     3

$US_JP
data frame with 0 columns and 0 rows

$CA_JP
  Group
1     4
```

Would it be possible to create this as a for-loop?

Answer (score 0):

Sure that looks doable with a nested for loop. There's no need to copy the initial list. The loop can iterate over the same list. I'd suggest using dplyr for it's handy filter and select functions

```
require(dplyr)
comb_list <- list()

for (i in 1:length(list1)) {
  for (j in 1:length(list1)) {
    # don't intersect country with itself
    if (names(list1)[i] != names(list1)[j]) {

      value <- filter(list1[[i]], Group %in% list1[[j]]$Group)
      value <- select(value, Group)
      
      name <- paste0(names(list1)[i], "_", names(list1[j]))
      name_alt <- paste0(names(list1)[j], "_", names(list1[i]))

      #don't store equivalent country intersections i.e. US_CA and CA_US
      if (!name %in% names(comb_list) & !name_alt %in% names(comb_list)) {
        comb_list[[name]] <- value
      }
    }
  }
}

print(comb_list)
$US_CA
  Group
1     2
2     3

$US_JP
[1] Group
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)

$CA_JP
  Group
1     4
```